# Show User Location in MapView

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, cllocation

I'm writing an App with a mapView showing some Annotations.

Now I want to show the User's current location in the mapView. I get the current Location using this code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)location
```

I get the details of the current location in the Log

```
2013-10-14 12:03:34.291 AppName[13200:a0b] (
"<+7.35000000,+47.32000000> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/14/13, 12:03:34 PM Central European Summer Time")
```

Now I don't get the location into the mapView as this blue pulsing dot.

Please give some hints.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can enable the userlocation by this:

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

if you want to center on this location:

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
```

if you are using:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
    return nil;
}

// etc...


}
```

Comment: Thanks, I now have the red PinAnnotation but I would like to have the blue pulsing dot

Comment: mapView.showsUserLocation = YES; if you set showsUserLocation to YES you must have to see the blue pulsing dot. zoom out of your map view, and you will see it , if you are using simulator, it won't show you your current location, it can be in USA. " Simulator by default you it will show some location in USA. If you want to change that location, in iOS Simulator menu, go to Debug -> Location -> Custom Location. There you can set the latitude and longitude and test the app accordingly. This works with mapkit and also with CLLocationManager."

Comment: I'm testing the App on my iPhone and the current location is a red Pin (callout saying "current location"

Answer (score 3):

In iOS10 I could not get the blue dot for the user location to show until adding the key NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription to my Info.plist, with a string description of how location info would be used in the app.

Answer (score 1):

In xCode 9 you could do it with storyboard file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same because I removed my type check code for AnnotationViews because I didn't need that anymore. So I made a Swift version of @incmiko's answer.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    guard !annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) else { return nil }

    //create annotation view

    return MKAnnotationView()
}
```